# After updating sSMTP to version 2.61 I cannot send mail via gmail

Tags: ssmtp

I updated sSMTP to version 2.61 and now when I try to us it I receive the following error:

```
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

I can connect via telnet to their address, but sSMTP seems to get tripped up and Im not sure what changed after the update.

Here is the `ssmtp.conf`

```
root=XXXXX@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
RewriteDomain=gmail.com
Hostname=localhost
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=Yes
AuthUser=XXXXX
AuthPass=XXXXX
FromLineOverride=yes
```

Output when connecting via telnet:

```
[root@soupcan sbin]# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 74.125.142.108...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP l7sm7330049igx.2 - gsmtp
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection l7sm7330049igx.2 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And the output when I try to use `sSMTP`

```
[root@soupcan sbin]# /usr/sbin/ssmtp -v XXXXX@gmail.com < /home/user/Documents/Scripts/msg.txt
[<-] 220 mx.google.com ESMTP f5sm7367852igc.4 - gsmtp
[->] EHLO localhost
[<-] 250 CHUNKING
[->] STARTTLS
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
ssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
```

**EDIT**
Turning on debug logging I now see this, Im still digging:

```
SSL not working: certificate verify failed (20)
```

**EDIT 2**
This has been resolved by adding the following to my `ssmtp.conf` file

```
TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Found information from [HERE](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1674889) and [HERE](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1004998)

Comment: This is what works for me, on Ubuntu 16.04 and on Raspbian.   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail/363815#363815

Comment: You need to be using this:  `mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has been resolved by adding the following to my `ssmtp.conf` file

```
TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Found information from [HERE](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1674889) and [HERE](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1004998)

Comment: It was failing for me until commented out #UseTLSCert=YES, TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt, UseTLS=YES, UseSTARTTLS=YES, FromLineOverride=YES, Hostname=/run hostname command to find out/, RewriteDomain=my.domain.ext, mailhub=smtp.office365.com:587

Answer (score 3):

FYI -- For Ubuntu the .crt file is in a different place and should read:

```
TLS_CA-File=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Adding this enabled me to connect to my SMTP server via STARTTLS on port 587 with the settings:

```
mailhub=smtp.{myserver}.com:587
AuthUser={username}    
AuthPass={password}
UseSTARTTLS=YES 
UseTLS=NO
TLS_CA_File=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

My mail server is configured to use STARTTLS and not SSL or TLS.

If I set `UseTLS=YES`, it fails.  It has to be exclusively `UseSTARTTLS=YES`, not both.  I don't know if other mail servers can do both at the same time, but mine does not.

Answer (score 1):

Use the setup found here:

[Simplest way to send one-line mail out via command line using gmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363814/simplest-way-to-send-one-line-mail-out-via-command-line-using-gmail)

Excerpt:

```
root=rpi3abc@gmail
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=rpi3abc@gmail.com
AuthPass=testing123
UseTLS=YES
```

It is as simple as that.