# Simplest way to send one-line mail out via command line using gmail?

Tags: debian, raspbian, lubuntu, ssmtp, gmail

Using Raspbian and Ubunntu 16.04 LTS so need a generic Linux solution.

Requirement is simple:

**I need a way to send one-line email messages from the command line.**

I have set up a gmail account just for this particular Rpi3, with the address of rpi3abc@gmail.com - with no 2FA

So now I need to be able to send one-line mail messages from anywhere (including cron) without user intervention.

---

I also would like it to be able to send text files; basically, anything from `stdin`.

Comment: do you want that your message come from this particular address, rpi3abc@gmail.com or is it OK for you that message comes from your_username@localhost?

Comment: It does come from rpi3abc@gmail.com so I know my computer is communicating to me.  I use it in cron jobs, mostly.

Comment: NOTE: from May 30, 2022 Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Answer (score 52, accepted):

---

**The simplest answer to sending one-line messages via gmail is to use ssmtp**

---

Install it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

Edit `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` to look like this:

```
root=rpi3abc@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:465
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=rpi3abc@gmail.com
AuthPass=testing123
UseTLS=YES
```

---

Send a one-liner like so:

```
echo "Testing...1...2...3" | ssmtp myusername@gmail.com
```

or

```
printf "Subject: Test\n\nTesting...1...2...3" | ssmtp myusername@gmail.com
```

Then, true to *nix, you just get the prompt back in a few seconds.

Check your myusername@gmail.com account, and voila, it is there!

---

This also works well when sending a file, as so:

```
cat program.py | ssmtp myotherusername@yahoo.com
```

And the program will show up in the mailbox

If the file is a text file, it can have a first line that says `Subject:  xxxxxx`

This can be used with various cron jobs can send me data with subject lines indicating the content.

---

This will work with anything that prepares a message that is piped into ssmtp via stdin.

---

For more details such as securing these files against other users and such, visit this article:

[Send Email from Raspberry Pi Command Line](http://www.algissalys.com/network-security/send-email-from-raspberry-pi-command-line)

---

Be sure to also look down below to the answer posted by `Rui` about locking down the `FROM:` address that might be changed in formatted message files, if necessary.

---

Now if only I could figure out how to send SMS the same way.

Comment: I also use `ssmtp` in my VMs, very lightweight. +1

Comment: Why not using the sendmail API from Python and sending it directly then?

Comment: To take this a step further, here are very simple instructions for including an image file as an attachment:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381131/simplest-way-to-send-mail-with-image-attachment-from-command-line-using-gmail

Comment: To answer Rui's question:  `sendmail` alone does not have the MTA - Mail Transport Agent to communicate outside the machine. By default, since Unixen are multi-user by design, `sendmail` will send messages to other users in the same box but not outside.   `ssmtp` is the MTA that I think is simplest to configure for gmail.

Comment: The `sendmail` API deliver both to the individual users or to the current MTA. The problem is that the From field can only be changed by root. Not to confuse the sendmail daemon with the historically sendmail compatible API.

Comment: spent forever trying to setup postix this worked! one note to anyone reading this, the conf has a typo, the root parameter should be gmail.com not gmail.

Comment: For Gmail, you now need `UseSTARTTLS=Yes` and `mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587` and `hostname=localhost`. Took me hours to get it right :)

Comment: The suggestion to send a Python file as standard input is not a good idea. It *could* work in some scenarios, but you could also get everything before the first empty line as headers and the rest in the body. A much more robust approach is to supply a simple set of valid headers and an empty line before the payload. This is remarkably workable as long as your payload is plain ASCII with limited line lengths, but breaks in interesting ways if you have Unicode, characters in some legacy 8-bit character set, long lines, or binary contents. Then you need MIME, which is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: **Very important** make sure you [Enable SMTP by Allowing less secure apps for your gmail account](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) . [More instructions Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-NYmDWiFjU).

Comment: `E: Package 'ssmtp' has no installation candidate`

Comment: If you are using gmail's 2FA you need to create an "App Password"

Answer (score 11):

`ssmtp` is just one of many Sendmail wrappers.  All of these accept a message on standard input, and optionally a list of addresses as command-line arguments, and they all offer a binary named `sendmail` which implements (at least the basic features of) the traditional Sendmail command-line API.  But properly speaking, that message needs to be well-formed RFC822 message.  At minimum, it should have a `Subject:` header.

```
ssmtp address@example.com <<<$'Subject: testing 1...2...3'
```

(With `ssmtp`, `sendmail` is just a symlink to `ssmtp`.  Postfix, Exim, and I believe every other MTA which `Provides: mail-transport-agent` has a similar arrangement, except of course `sendmail` where the `sendmail` binary is "the real thing".)

More commonly, you can piece together a simple email message with a here document.

```
/usr/lib/sendmail -oi -t <<____HERE
Subject: testing
To: recipient@example.net

Here we interpolate the shell variable $result
____HERE
```

(The Sendmail `-t` option says to take the recipient list from the headers of the message you receive on standard input.  The precise path to Sendmail will differ between platforms.)

Another common variation is to combine the output of a few commands.  Take care to have an empty line (a "neck") between the headers and the message body.

```
( printf "Subject: random number\n\n"
  dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -D -An ) |
sendmail elsewhere@example.org
```

For anything beyond very simple ASCII text-only messages, you need to understand how to compose a proper MIME message, at which point it usually makes more sense to use a tool like `mutt`.  Some platforms have a `mail` or `mailx` which knows how to send attachments and non-ASCII text, but this is not fully portable.

The challenge here is not finding a client which can take an email message and attempt to send it, it is to configure it for the specifics of Gmail, which requires the MTA to know the user name and password to use for the remote server in order to be able to use it as the outgoing smarthost.

Behind the scenes, most clients like `mutt`, `mailx`, etc typically just run `sendmail` behind the scenes to get the message off the system.

Comment: I wan't having much luck with using sendmail directly; hence turning to ssmtp.  Upvote for your answer.  By the way, in order to send images as attachments I found the simplest way posssible.  I don't have to even think about MIME.  I just use mpack, as described here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381131/simplest-way-to-send-mail-with-image-attachment-from-command-line-using-gmail

Answer (score 8):

Adding to the OP own answer:

When configuring `ssmtp`, you may also forbid or allow users from defining the From, and also override the domain; you might want to do that for several reasons including the message not falling in the Spam folder.

You can add to `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`:

```
# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=my_internet_domain.uk

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Please note that while YES can be used in a home raspberry, it might not be advisable in a multi-user system from the security point of view.

Comment: Upvote.  Excellent info.

Answer (score 4):

I'm really partial to using `mailx` for this:

```
echo "Message body." | mailx -s "Subject line" -a /path/attachment.txt -r "Sender's Name<sender@email.com>" -c recipient2@email.com recipient1@email.com
```

Comment: Several of the options here will not be available on many non-Debian/non-BSD systems. The `-a` option in particular would be wonderful if it was universally supported, but just browse the `mailx` questions here to see that this is quite certainly not the case.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with "mail"?

> echo "Hi there" | mail -s "Important mail" user@example.com

"mail" being /etc/alternative link to /usr/bin/bsd-mailx from bsd-mailx package. I believe it's there by default. Great utility for sending mail from cron scripts, for example.

Works on Ubuntu and FreeBSD as well.

Comment: `mailx` is just a front end. It requires some MTA to be configured to actually get the message off the local system. There are multiple incompatible versions in common use, though if your target platform is Debian only, you can rely on reasonably recent BSD behavior.

Comment: Gmail will block this. This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass 421-4.7.0 authentication

Comment: How can you fix this @MichaelRogers

Answer (score 2):

I use sendEmail to send simple automated e-mails via an external provider's SMTP server:

```
sendEmail -q -f "me@mail.com" -u "mySubject" -t "someone@mail.org" -s "my.smtp.com" -o tls=yes -xu "mySmtpUser" -xp "mySmtpPw" -m "myMessage"
```

I pass everything on one line, so doing this on a command line would likely show all parameters (including smtp password) to all users, if they run a `ps -ef` while I am running the command. I use it within a shell script.

Comment: This is not a standard install, and there are multiple clients with this name.  I guess you are referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SendEmail. Is it available as a Debian package?

Comment: Good thinking about the shell script, like on a multi-user system.  I like that my password is in a file deep in the guts of the machine.  I only wish I could store a hashed password instead of clear text.

Comment: I was refering to this package: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=sendemail

Comment: I don't see this answer demonstrating that it works with gmail as specified in the original question.

Comment: This does work with gmail, ex: ` -s smtp.gmail.com -o tls=yes -xp your_gmail_password -s smtp.gmail.com:587`

Answer (score 2):

My server is CEntOS 7, and has sendmail but not mailx etc. Rather than install a new program I tested using sendmail directly, and found that this works:

```
echo -e "From: you@whatever\nTo: you@gmail.com\nSubject: this is the subject\n\nThis is the body,\nwith multiple lines." | sendmail -t
```

For me this seems to be the simplest way to send a short email, as it does not require running or configuring a server or daemon, and can be done in a single command line.

The idea is that a message will simply alert me that a certain program threw an error, without revealing any potentially confidential info, and then I'll SSH to the server to inspect its logs. This way there's no need to bother with complications like attaching files or encrypting the transport.

Notes:

- `-e` tells echo to interpret '\n' and other escapes.
- `-t` tells sendmail to get recipient addresses from 'To:' in the message header.
- If the mail does not arrive, use `tail /var/log/maillog`to see error messages.
- If sending to your gmail address, make a filter at gmail to keep them out of the junk folder.
- This sendmail is actually 'sendmail.postfix' (which might be normal); there's a man page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sendmail.postfix)

Comment: Your system must have a MTA installed that is working with `sendmail`  - but I don't see this answer demonstrating that it works with gmail as specified in the original question...

Comment: @SDsolar  You're right. Postfix is running on my server, and I didn't know. Seems like it's standard with a Centos install; maybe DigitalOcean configured it. It's not listening on a public port. As for sending through gmail, my point is that you don't need to, you can send direct from your own server, if you're sending only to yourself. (I might ask my own question and move this answer over, if it doesn't fit here.)

Answer (score 0):

Try https://batsign.me which a very simple service that avoids email server & client setup.